# Can't make my JS Bin working "require" is not defined error react/redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to make this JS Bin example https://jsbin.com/pineyec/edit?html,console,output works but I've got the following error :

```
"ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js:4:28099), <anonymous>:8:14) ...blablaba...
```

Don't know if it's directly related to React though... Anyone ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare to https://gist.github.com/zvweiss/66517767889a7ed9895a

You are not able to use `import` in the browser, look to the top of that gist to see how he pulls the bits you need out of the Globals that are created.